# How to set a timeout to a specific service function in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, asynchronous

I am creating an app in which some actions in the service need to be asynchronous.

I set the global timeout for 1 minute in the `AsyncConfigurer`.

This is OK for most of the actions, but in some actions, I need to set a longer timeout. For example in the following service action:

```
@Async
public Object someLongFunction() {
```

Can someone tell me how to set a specific timeout for a specific action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the return type of the function to `java.util.concurrent.Future`

It has `java.util.concurrent.Future#get(long, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)` method that you can leverage to define custom timeout